# tabularx inside \NewDocumentEnvironment (xparse package)

Tags: tables, environments, tabularx, xparse

I am trying to set up a new environment using xparse and its \NewDocumentEnvironment including a table.

My MWE looks like this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{\testtable}{m}
    {%
    \table%
        \tabularx{\textwidth}{#1}%
    }%
    {%
        \endtabularx%
    \endtable%
}

\begin{document} 

 \begin{testtable}{ccc}
  0 & 0 & 0 \\
  1 & 0 & 1 \\
  2 & 1 & 0 \\
  3 & 1 & 1
 \end{testtable}

\end{document}
```

Compiling fails with

```
14:Undefined conrol sequence }
```

with line 14, being the closing '}' of my environment.

I stripped the example as much as possible, to make it work, but it doesn't compile.

What's wrong here?

Comment: Erh, isn't this just an error 40 (the error that is 40 cm from the screen)? Replace `\texttable` by `testtable`, then this compiles just fine.

Comment: BTW: why are you using tabularx in this case when you are not using the X columns?

Comment: \NewDocumentEnvironment{testtable}{m}
    {%
    \table%
        \tabularx{\textwidth}{#1}%
    }%
    {%
        \endtabularx%
    \endtable%
}

Comment: you have to have at least one X column if you want tabularx to do anything useful.

Comment: Note that tex's error message is not as you show it is much clearer: `! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \testtable`   If your editor is just showing the corrupted form of the error message that you showed then that is a mis-feature of the editor, which you should report.

Comment: @DavidCarlisleThanks for pointing this out. That error would have been much clearer. I use kile 3 as Latex IDE and did not know it obfuscates errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\NewDocumentEnvironment{testtable}{m}
    {%
    \table%
        \tabularx{\textwidth}{#1}%
    }%
    {%
        \endtabularx%
    \endtable%
}
```

Use like above

Answer (score 0):

The MWE compiles just fine, if you replace

```
\NewDocumentEnvironment{\testtable}{m}
```

by

```
\NewDocumentEnvironment{testtable}{m}
```

after all, it is an environment you are creating, not a mere macro.